# How to remove a string element from a list in Python .remove is not working for me

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, function, return

I am trying to remove strings from a list after they have been chosen to avoid getting the same word again but when I try to .remove or .pop it doesn't remove the word. Why is this and how could i sort it?

I also tried to create a copy of the word incase it got removed before returning the word from the function, would this affect the word if its already chosen?

Thanks for any help, I am new to programming, as you could probably tell!

```
def choose_a_word_easy():  # function for choosing random  easy word.
    words = ['ant', 'bee', 'cat', 'dog', 'egg', 'hat', 'golf', 'jelly', 'king', 'bird', 'hot', 'cold', 'fish', 'log',
             'dad', 'mum', 'goal', 'help', 'file', 'neat', 'car', 'moon', 'eye', 'tree', 'rice', 'ice', 'speed', 'rat',
             'water', 'rain', 'snow', 'spoon', 'light', 'gold', 'zoo', 'oil', 'goat', 'yoga', 'judo', 'japan', 'hello']

    pick = random.choice(words)  # randomly choose any word from the list.
    # p1 = pick
    words.remove(pick)
    return pick
```

Comment: How are you checking to see if the word has been removed?

Comment: When i run the program the word can pop up several times in the quizz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring your list *inside* the function `choose_a_word_easy`, a new list is created on every call. You want the same list to be reused on every call. Do so by creating the list outside the function's scope and passing it as an argument.

```
words = ['ant', 'bee', 'cat', 'dog', ...]

def pick_and_remove(lst):
    pick = random.choice(lst)
    lst.remove(pick)
    return pick

pick = pick_and_remove(words)

print(pick) # 'bee'
print(words) # ['ant', 'cat', 'dog', ...]
```

Note that your function can be made slightly more efficient by randomly picking an index and poping it.

```
def pick_and_remove(lst):
    i = random.randrange(len(lst))
    return lst.pop(i)
```